# Undefined method 'encodePassword'. - error in Apiplateform security encoder undefined

Tags: api, symfony, security, encoder

[image]

I have a problem in my symfony security api in the service **PasswordService**. It can't find the encoder

I can't guess what should I do.
This is my security.yaaml file:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;


class PasswordService
{
    /**
     * @var PasswordService
     */
    private $userPasswordEncoder;

    /**
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder
     */
    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $userPasswordEncoder)
    {
        $this->userPasswordEncoder = $userPasswordEncoder;
    }

    /**
     * @param object $entity
     * @param string $password
     * @return string
     */
    
    public function encode(object $entity, string $password): string
    {
        return $this->userPasswordEncoder->encodePassword($entity, $password);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     * @return int
     */
    public function formatRequirement(string $password)
    {
        return preg_match('#^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W)#', $password);
    }

    /**
     * @param object $entity
     * @param string $password
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isValid(object $entity, string $password): bool
    {
        return $this->userPasswordEncoder->isPasswordValid($entity, $password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real error you just have a wrong annotation here:

```
/**
 * @var PasswordService <========
 */
private $userPasswordEncoder;
```

If you remove it, it should be fine. (Or replace it with UserPasswordEncoderInterface)